# How to share notes between two objects

Tags: custom-object, relationships

I have two objects subject and subject requirements.

The subject has a master details relationship with the subject requirement. what I would like to do is if I write something in the subject requirement records note, how can I add the same notes on the subject records too.

Comment: I can assume your meaning, but I think it would be better to state your precise problem. Which record is the parent? Which record is the child? Which one is the one that has the field? Which field on that object is being set? How are you wanting that change to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void SharedNotes(list<ContentDocumentLink> newcontentdocument){
    List<Id> listOfContentdocId= new  List<Id>();
    Set<Id> contactidList= new  Set<Id>();
    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList =New List<ContentDocumentLink>();     
    for(ContentDocumentLink cd: newcontentdocument){
        if(cd.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()== '<ObjectName>'){
            contactidList.add(cd.LinkedEntityId);
        }
    }
    if(contactidList.size()>0){
        list<ContentNote> ContentNote_list =[SELECT Id,LatestPublishedVersionId,TextPreview,Title FROM ContentNote WHERE Id =:newcontentdocument[0].ContentDocumentId];
        Set<Id> Set_Ids = New Set<Id>();
        list<ObjectName> obj_list =[Select Id From Objectname Where Id In:contactidList];
        For(Object obj:obj_list){
            Set_Ids.add(obj.Id);
        }
        for(Id cd: Set_Ids){
              ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cdl.ContentDocumentId = newcontentdocument[0].ContentDocumentId; 
                cdl.LinkedEntityId =cd;
                cdl.ShareType = 'V'; 
                cdlList.add(cdl);
        }
        insert cdlList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is a _code dump_ (code with little to no explanation about how it works). Code dumps are typically poor answers that generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments (that didn't work, try this instead, etc...) which makes it harder for others to follow. Good answers will typically explain what the issue is, and how the solution works. You should [edit] your answer to add additional detail.